# whitelisting IP addresses for functioning of mirror site

Tags: .htaccess

I really need help regarding my website's mirror site functioning..my website is elementlimousine.com and the mirror site url is elementslimousine.net

I am not much of a techie so excuse my ignorance and simplicity of language.

I have a website for which I am getting search engine marketing done through third party. They way they do it is make a mirror site (with a different url), which will take information from original site and display it to the user.

But the problem we are facing is on clicking the mirror site url, a 500 error shows up. The team said it is happening because the mirror site is talking very frequently to the original site. So the only solution according to them is white list their IP addresses:

74.122.36.157 
204.14.212.132 
74.122.37.11 
74.122.36.0 – 74.122.36.255 (256 IPs) 
74.122.37.0 – 74.122.37.255 (256 IPs)

But it is still not working and the campaign has been paused..so now elementslimousine.net does work

1. Did I put the code wrong or at wrong place in htaccess file?
2. Is there anything else that can be done to make mirroring work?

I will really appreciate any help in this!
Thanks

According to other posts, I opened my .htacces file and changed code to this:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


order allow, deny

allow from 74.122.36.157
allow from 204.14.212.132
allow from 74.122.37.11
allow from 74.122.36.0 – 74.122.36.255 
allow from 74.122.37.0 – 74.122.37.255 

# BEGIN wtwp_cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    # Text
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType text/html .html .htm
    AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
    AddType text/plain .txt
    AddType text/xml .xml

    # Image
    AddType image/gif .gif
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
    AddType image/png .png
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz

    # Video
    AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
    AddType video/avi .avi
    AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe

    # PDF
    AddType application/pdf .pdf

    # Flash
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf

    # Font
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType application/x-font-otf .otf

    # Audio
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
    AddType audio/ogg .ogg
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/wma .wma

    # Zip/Tar
    AddType application/x-tar .tar
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
    AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On

    # Text
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600

    # Image
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000

    # Video
    ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000

    # PDF
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000

    # Flash
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000

    # Font
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000

    # Audio
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000

    # Zip/Tar
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:css|js|htm|html|rtf|rtx|txt|xml|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|svg|svgz|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|mov|qt|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|pdf|swf|ttf|ttc|eot|otf|mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma|tar|gz|gzip|zip)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
        Header unset ETag
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:css|js|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|pdf|swf|ttf|ttc|eot|otf)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset Set-Cookie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END wtwp_cache

# BEGIN wtwp_security
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
<Files "wp-config.php">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
Options -Indexes
# END wtwp_security
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax error.

Try this block and replace your relevant code:

```
order deny,allow
deny from All
allow from 74.122.36.157
allow from 204.14.212.132
allow from 74.122.37.11
allow from 74.122.36.0 74.122.36.255 
allow from 74.122.37.0 74.122.37.255
```

MOre details about it: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html